# React Native error: Cannot find module 'jest-serializer'

Tags: android, ios, macos, react-native, mobile

any one can help me? i have a problem when i run 'npm start'. this is the

**Error Message**

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Have you tried `npm install jest-serializer`? Then `npm start`

Answer (score 0):

Try to run npm install jest-serializer before doing npm start. If that is still not working,

```
rm -rf node modules
npm install
npm start
```